# Passing audio files between ViewControllers?

Tags: audio, viewcontroller

I have created a Sound Board application that works great in a single view controller, but I want to add multiple soundboards/ pages to this app and can not figure out how to make the audio on any other view controller? When I add the audio files to my second view controller the sound does not play? Is there a simple way to pass these audio files between the view controllers so that sound will work on my second page?

I guess the simplified version of my question is: How to add sound to other view controllers so they can be played when the button is clicked?

Thanks Stackoverflow community you have taught me more than you know! This may be a simple question, but I can seem to find the answer anywhere.